# How to get selected row from UITableView with Search Display Controller

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller, didselectrowatindexpath

I have my search display view controller based off [TableSearch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html).

Normally, following expression gives selected index row:

```
self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row
```

However while in search mode, selected row can be obtained using:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row
```

I use the above indices to remove respective rows (from my back end arrays) soon after some processing - at the end of didSelectRowAtIndexPath. The arrays I use are listContent and filteredListContent - as per the Apple example.

My issue is, while in search mode, I remove a row using:

```
[self.filteredListContent removeObjectAtIndex: self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row]
```

However, at the same time, I also want to remove the same object from self.listContent because when I return to non-search mode, that row should not appear.

I saw that self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row does not update regularly while in search results view. Instead, it gives the last selected row before I entered the search results view.

Off course, I can put some content into my array objects so that both indexes can be cross-referenced. But is there any efficient solution other than that? I think table view should have this mechanism.

And yes, I already do following in my viewWillAppear:

```
   [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine for me...

```
 #pragma mark - delete row
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {

        if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
             // searching mode
        {
            // find row (index) from listContent
            arrayObject = [filteredlistContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSUInteger fooIndex = [listContent indexOfObject: arrayObject];
            NSLog(@"index listContent %u", fooIndex);
            //remove from listContent
            [self.listContent removeObjectAtIndex:fooIndex];
            [self.tableView reloadData];

            //remove from filteredlistContent
            [self.filteredlistContent removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        }
        else  //  tableView mode
        {
        [self.listContent removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
    }
}
```